# Why won't my kernel.response event listener modify my response?

Tags: symfony

I don't find the reason why my subsequent kernel.response event listener won't modify my response here. Do you encountered this problem too before, or is there a misprint into the lines ?

Context: users will have a 10-items visit history attached to them, under Symfony3.

```
public function onResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
{
    $request = $event->getRequest();

    if(!$event->isMasterRequest() || !preg_match('#^dm_.*#', $request->get('_route'))){
        return;
    }

    $history = $request->cookies->get('history');
    if(!$history)$history = "[]";
    $history = json_decode($history, true);

    $addon = [
        'route' => $request->get('_route'),
        'route_params' => $request->attributes->get('_route_params'),
        'url' => $request->getRequestUri(),
        'date' => new \Datetime
    ];
    $history[] = $addon;
    $history = array_slice(
        $history,
        -10
    );

    $cookie = new Cookie('history', json_encode($history), time() + 3600);

    $response = $event->getResponse();
    $response->headers->setCookie($cookie);
}
```

I added some var_dump()s, to check that event was caught (and it was). I also tested to modify headers elsewhere, and it works fine. So, just here, I don't see why it doesn't.

Comment: Do you mean that the cookie is not being set?

Comment: Yes. I don't see why, but the problem is now solved, without special change. Maybe the cache is involved in any sort of way. Thanks